# PL/SQL Update command is not updating the record in data base

Tags: sql, plsql

I have below stored procedure written

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EmployeeProcedure
(id IN NUMBER, name IN VARCHAR, salary IN NUMBER,
stmt IN VARCHAR
) AS

BEGIN
IF stmt='INSERT' then
     INSERT INTO Employee(employee_id,name,salary) VALUES(id, name, salary);
END IF;

IF stmt='UPDATE' then
     update employee set name=name, salary=salary
         where employee_id=id;
END IF;

IF stmt='DELETE' then
   Delete from employee where employee_id=id;
END IF;

END EmployeeProcedure;
```

This is the data available in Employee table

```
EMPLOYEE_ID NAME    SALARY  TITLE
2   Ranjan  40000   Manager
3   Stella  5000    President
4   Fred    500 Janitor
10  Ranjan  3000    -
1   John    64876   -
```

when i am executing this stored procedure using below statment

```
begin
EmployeeProcedure(10,'John',78987,'UPDATE');
end;
```

I am getting statement processed. But record with employee id= 10 is not getting updated. Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Comment: Just to be sure: you are committing at some point in your transaction, correct?

Comment: which DB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use variables with the same name as the field you want to update

This wouldn't do nothing:

```
 SET name = name, salary = salary
```

Set your variable like:

```
 str_name,  int_salary
```

Then you will have

```
 SET name = str_name, salary = int_salary
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the commit neither in the call to your procedure nor within the procedure itself.

If your execution runs from the anonymous block you stated, be sure to issue commit afterwards.

Also as Juan Carlos Oropeza stated, having your parameters with the same name as the column, has proven to be a bad practice, append letter "p" to differentiate a parameter from the column name as in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EmployeeProcedure
(p_id IN NUMBER, p_name IN VARCHAR, p_salary IN NUMBER,
p_stmt IN VARCHAR
) AS

BEGIN
IF p_stmt='INSERT' then
     INSERT INTO Employee(employee_id,name,salary) VALUES(p_id, p_name, p_salary);
END IF;

IF p_stmt='UPDATE' then
     update employee set name=p_name, salary=p_salary
         where employee_id=p_id;
END IF;

IF p_stmt='DELETE' then
   Delete from employee where employee_id=p_id;
END IF;

END EmployeeProcedure;
```

Comment: thanks Jair, It is working now.. could you please also help me with one more condition IF p_stmt='SELECT' then Select * from employee; end if;      I tried this code but it is not working..

Comment: You are welcome, I posted the answer to your new question in another answer, in this same topic, since my reply used more characters than allowed in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Glad I did help.

About using a 'select' statement in your procedure, I think you will have to make a little change to implement a return value, simply because using a select statement as such in a PL/SQL block is not possible, unless you use it in an explicit/implicit cursor.

I imagine something like this could do it:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EmployeeProcedure(
    p_id IN NUMBER, 
    p_name IN VARCHAR, 
    p_salary IN NUMBER,
    p_stmt IN VARCHAR, 
    p_CURSOR in out SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
BEGIN
    IF p_stmt='INSERT' then
         INSERT INTO Employee(employee_id,name,salary) VALUES(p_id, p_name, p_salary);
    END IF;

    IF p_stmt='UPDATE' then
         update employee set name=p_name, salary=p_salary
             where employee_id=p_id;
    END IF;

    IF p_stmt='DELETE' then
       Delete from employee where employee_id=p_id;
    END IF;

    IF p_stmt='SELECT' then
        /*open the explicit cursor*/
        open p_cursor for
            select * 
            from employee 
            where employee_id = p_id;
    END IF;

END EmployeeProcedure;
```

And then you will have to read the cursor this way:

```
declare
    cur       SYS_REFCURSOR;
    data_row  employee%rowtype;
begin
    EmployeeProcedure(1,null,null,'SELECT', cur);--opens cursor
    loop 
        fetch cur into data_row; --reads one row
        exit when cur%notfound; --exits when you reach the end of rows

        --at this point you can access every row in your table.
        dbms_output.put_line(data_row.employee_id);
    end loop;
    close cur; --always remember close every cursor you open to keep your DBA happy.
 end;
```

Comment: could you pls also help me with aggregate function?  and how can i run the query when p_stmt=Insert/update/delete?

Comment: Hi @ranjanjaiswal sorry but I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve now. Do you want to allow multiple operations in one call by passing p_stmt='insert/update/delete'?